# Socket.IO storing active users

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have a chat application project going on and I used to store all active users in an array, pushing their userIds, sockets, and socket.ids, and then simply slicing from the array once the user disconnects. However, once there will be a different server I will encounter a problem. Memory sharing. One server wouldn't know what 'activeUsers' the other has and vice-versa.
Is there a quick and easy to way to solve this? Perhaps I could store these sessions in MongoDB? Or is Redis is the only option?

```
  io.sockets.on('connection', async (socket, next) => {
  const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
  const decoded = await jwt.decodeId(token);
  const userId = decoded.id;
  await socketUtil.handleUserConnection(userId, socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', async () => {
    await socketUtil.handleUserDisconnect(socket.id);
  });
});

export const handleUserConnection = async (userId, socketId) => {
  const sum = await Sock.countDocuments();
  const socket = await Sock.create({
    leasedAt: new Date(),
    userId,
    socketId,
  });
  if (!socket) {
    logger.error('Socket creation error:', socketId);
  }
  logger.info(userId + ' connected (' + sum + ')');
};

export const handleUserDisconnect = async (socketId) => {
  const sum = await Sock.countDocuments();
  logger.info('User disconnected (' + sum + ')');
  await Sock.deleteMany({ socketId });
};
```

Comment: If you change the session handler to express-session you can easily set the session store to redis.

Comment: Looks like there are about 50 different types of session stores, in addition to Redis that you can use with `express-session` as `yeya` mentioned - https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores - looks like there are 3 different ways to use `mongo` with `express-session`